# Full text search in MySQL (PHP) with letters under ft_min_word_len

Tags: php, mysql

My `ft_min_word_len` in MySQL is set to 4. When I try to full text search something with 2 or 3 letters, I get no results. So I'm using this code to get full-text search for these short words:

```
$table = $this->db->shop_products();

$where = '';
preg_match_all("~[\\pL\\pN_]+('[\\pL\\pN_]+)*~u", stripslashes($find), $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $part) {
    $isFirst = empty($where);
    $regexp = "REGEXP '" . addslashes($part) . "'";

    if(!$isFirst) $where .= " AND (";
    $where .= "name {$regexp} OR content {$regexp}";
    if(!$isFirst) $where .= ")";
}

return $table->where($where)->limit(5)->fetchAll();
```

This code works fine, but it has problem with diacritic, like `č, á, é, í...`. For example, I have product called `bé` and when I want to find for just `be`, it will not show me that product, because it doesn't have same letters.

**Note:** I'm using [NotORM](http://www.notorm.com/) for MySQL queries, but I hope you know how does work that `$table->where(...`.

Comment: Why not set `ft_min_word_len` to 2?

Comment: On my website hosting I cannot do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution, but with the PHP, not MySQL. Right in the `foreach` I put this line `$part = diagriticToNormal($part);` - so it will change special characters into classic ones, or how to name it. Under this answer there is that function. I know it is lame, not good for performance etc... But as a start it is enought.

```
function diagriticToNormal($text) {
    $charsMap = array(
        'a' => array('á', 'ä'),
        'c' => array('č'),
        'd' => array('ď'),
        'e' => array('é', 'ě'),
        'i' => array('í'),
        'l' => array('ľ', 'ĺ'),
        'n' => array('ň'),
        'o' => array('ô', 'ó'),
        'r' => array('ŕ', 'ř'),
        's' => array('š'),
        't' => array('ť'),
        'u' => array('ú', 'ů'),
        'y' => array('ý'),
        'z' => array('ž'),
    );

    foreach($charsMap as $real => $alt) {
        $alt = implode('|', $alt);
        $text = str_replace(array(strtolower($real), strtoupper($real)), '[' . $real . '|' . $alt . ']', $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
```